# Failing to color line using VBO

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am trying and failing to draw a line with color using glkit / OpenGL Es2.  I can draw the line, but it comes out as black.

My current approach is attempting to use a VBO containing both positional and color data.

Set-up:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[2];
    float Color[4];
} LinePoint;

LinePoint line[] =
{
    {{0.0, 0.0},{1.0,0.0,0.0,1}},
    {{2.0, 3.0},{1.0,0.0,0.0,1}}
};

glGenBuffers(1, &_lineBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _lineBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(LinePoint)*2,line,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

In my drawInRect method:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _lineBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Position));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Color));



    // Set the line width
    glLineWidth(50.0);

    // Render the line

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    }
```

Comment: Can we see your shader code?

Comment: No, because I have none!  Do I need to learn how to use shaders too?  (Good grief!  All this to plot a line.)

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have a fixed pipeline, and requires shaders. As far as I can tell, GLKit has support for providing some pre-baked shaders so that you don't have to write your own for simple use cases. I haven't used that, so I won't be much help. You can probably find examples. GLKBaseEffect seems to be the key class in providing that functionality.

Comment: Thanks.  Some progress - using 'self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = NO;' gives me the desired red line.  Unfortunately, now all my textures (drawn elsewhere) are also colored red!